# CMake, when use FindFoo.cmake or FooConfig.cmake (and other clarifications)

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm crashing my brain on cmake. I haven't understood properly all its power but everywhere I'm reading about that it worths to learn it so.. here I am.

I'd like to set up a building enviroment where to use some of the good libraries I'm normally use (Qt, OpenGL, OpenCV, etc) and I can write easily both applications or modules (let's call them modules, for now) to use in the applications.

The folder structure I have in mind is something like:

```
/apps/app_with_foo_and_qt_gui
/apps/app_with_foo
/apps/app_with_foo_and_foo1
/modules/foo
/modules/foo1
```

from what I get I need in the apps to use the command `find_package` for include in the foo or foo1, but my main point is that it seems this command is looking for both a find or config file, and I haven't understood the difference between them.

Then, my idea is to to have in each of my module a `built` folder where to put the compiled part of the module (for not compile it each time i compile an app that uses it) and a test folder where to put the test. But it is not very clear to me how to compile the tests.

Some clarification?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Find*.cmake and *Config.cmake, these two files accomplish the same task of finding and providing information about a package.  However, there method of interaction differs.  With Find*.cmake files, CMake will use them to search for the various details.  For instance, CMake's FindQt4.cmake file will search your system for qmake, and using that set various variables to use Qt4 with CMake.
On the other hand, *Config.cmake files contain pre-defined data about where various pieces of the package exist on the system.  For instance, if a Qt4Config.cmake file existed, it wouldn't query qmake for paths, but instead contain pre-computed paths for Qt4.  For more details, see  CMake's documentation about [find_package.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_package)

So, my recommendation for your project structure is too have foo and foo1 install as system libraries, and use a *Config.cmake file to find the various details about them.  Note that you don't have to install foo* libraries to the system, instead you could just install them to a local directory (either your built folder, or a general location like /modules/install, etc).

Then each app can just query for the appropriate pieces using CMake's [find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_package).

For creating the *Config.cmake files, CMake [has some documentation located here.](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file)

Comment: ok thanks but i don't need to install them, i just need the more easy way to load them from different application

Comment: You might be able to get the *Config.cmake file to work with a build folder, as it doesn't really care about installation.  It just records information.  However, I'd recommend installing the libraries anyways.  That way you can do development on the libraries without affecting your program's code.  Like I mentioned, you don't need to install system wide, a local folder will work just fine.  I personally use a ~/install folder to hold such things.

Comment: Can I see some example? do you have a public repository or something similar?